# "stack smashing detected" error from simple database query in Laravel Framework

Tags: php, pdo, laravel, odbc, freetds

I have a simple route that tests the database connection to a Microsoft SQL Server:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $db = DB::Connection("sams")->getPdo();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT 1");
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        echo
        print_r($row);
    }
    var_dump($db);

});
```

I'm on Fedora 20, using unixODBC and FreeTDS to connect to the database. Here's what versions of things I'm running (package versions):

```
php.x86_64           5.5.7-1.fc20       @updates                           
php-bcmath.x86_64    5.5.7-1.fc20       @updates                           
php-cli.x86_64       5.5.7-1.fc20       @updates                           
php-common.x86_64    5.5.7-1.fc20       @updates                           
php-devel.x86_64     5.5.7-1.fc20       @updates                           
php-gd.x86_64        5.5.7-1.fc20       @updates                           
php-mcrypt.x86_64    5.5.7-1.fc20       @updates                           
php-mssql.x86_64     5.5.7-1.fc20       @updates                           
php-odbc.x86_64      5.5.7-1.fc20       @updates                           
php-pdo.x86_64       5.5.7-1.fc20       @updates                           
php-pear.noarch      1:1.9.4-23.fc20    @fedora                            
php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 1.3.3-1.fc20      @updates                           
php-pecl-jsonc-devel.x86_64  1.3.3-1.fc20  @updates                           
php-process.x86_64   5.5.7-1.fc20       @updates                           
php-xml.x86_64      5.5.7-1.fc20        @updates
freetds.x86_64      0.91-9.gitb760a89.fc20 @fedora                            
freetds-devel.x86_64 0.91-9.gitb760a89.fc20  @fedora
unixODBC.x86_64      2.3.2-2.fc20       @fedora                            
unixODBC-devel.x86_64  2.3.2-2.fc20     @fedora
```

Here's my odbc.ini (obfuscated):

```
[SAMS]
Driver  = TDS
Description = SAMS Database
Servername = {Servername}
Port   = {Port}
Password = {password}
```

odbcinst.ini:

```
[TDS]
Description     = FreeTDS.org
Driver          = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib64/libtdsS.so
FileUsage       = 1
```

freetds.conf:

```
[SAMS]
Trace = Yes
TraceFile = /home/njones/sql.log
ForceTrace = Yes
host = {ipaddress}
port = {port}
tds version = 8.0
```

However, when I test this in the Laravel Development Server, I get the error below.

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: /usr/bin/php terminated
```

Answer (score 0):

[Installing PHP 5.5.8](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-apache-php-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) fixed this problem.